# How to fix potential lags while sculpting?

Tags: sculpting, performance

How does one fix sculpting lags in blender? I finally found the main culprit to why even super low poly count objects lag while sculpting.

Answer (score 1):

THE MAIN CULPRITE IS "DISPLAY IN VIEWPORT" found under Outliner>Toggles.

Hiding objects that aren't being used is useless performance wise. So instead of just hiding objects not in use also disable display in viewport for every object. The best hardware in the world won't make sculpting smooth if you don't do this and have allot of other objects with high poly count in the .blend file.

Other small performance boosts:

- Disable Cavity/ Matcap
- Turn off wireframe
- Turn off backface culling
- Don't constantly use the silhouette trick where one has one window in viewport shading and only has environment pass enabled
- reduce max amount of undo steps

How to get the biggest noticeable difference with the least spent money:

- Ram is super cheap and changes allot - 16-32 RAM
- Then CPU
- And GPU doesn't help much it's main purpose is for rendering and doesn't have much influence in solid view

Comment: I feel so relived, this has been driving me crazy